# How to stay undetected while scraping the latest post from a social media site that requires login?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, proxy

I've created a script using python in combination with selenium implementing proxies within it to log in to facebook and scrape the name of the user whose post is on top of my feed. I would like the script to do this every five minutes for an unlimited time.

As this continuous login may lead my account to ban, I thought to implement proxies within the script to do the whole stuff anonymously.

I've written so far:

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def get_first_user(random_proxy):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={random_proxy}')

    with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
        driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("username")
        driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("password",Keys.RETURN)
        user = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h4[@id][@class][./span[./a]]/span/a"))).text
        return user

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxies = [`list of proxies`]

    while True:
        random_proxy = proxies.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies)))
        print(get_first_user(random_proxy))
        time.sleep(60000*5)
```

> How to stay undetected while scraping data continuously from a site that requires authentication?

Comment: It looks like you are logging into your account, so this is not anonymous at all. Using a proxy also wouldn't matter, because Facebook still knows that it is you. If anything, it's going to look more suspicious, because your account is being logged into constantly from multiple locations.

Comment: bot detection has nothing to do with your ip or how many times you login.  Facebook is, for the most part, OK with bots... or at least they don't both to detect them.  Though if you use automated methods to create posts they will suspend your ability to post for a little bit (and mark the posts... they'll think YOU have been hacked).  It's worth noting that they do have APIs available.  This is the better way to go as it's direct and through facebook's own API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to continuously login into your `Facebook` account every 5 minutes to scrape content.  And using a random proxy address for each login would likely raise a *red flag* with `Facebook's` security rules  .

Instead of logging into `Facebook` every 5 minutes, I would recommend staying logged-in.  `Selenium` has a feature that *refreshes* a webpage being controlled by automation.  By using this method you could refresh your
`Facebook` feed at a predefined interval, such as 5 minutes.

The code below uses this refresh method to reload the page.  The code also checks from the user post at the top of your feed.

In testing I noted that `Facebook` uses some randomized tagging, which is likely used to mitigate **scraping**.  I also noted that `Facebook` changed the username formats on posts linked to groups, so more testing is required if you want the usernames linked to these posts.  I highly recommended conducting more tests to determine what user elements aren't being scraped correctly.

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

# global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')

driver.implicitly_wait(20)

driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("your_username")
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("your_password")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//button[text()='Log In']")).click()


# this function checks for a standard username tag
def user_element_exist():
    try:
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h4[@id][@class][./span[./a]]/span/a"):
            return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False


# this function looks for username linked to Facebook Groups at the top of your feed
def group_element():
    try:
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'jsc_c_')]/span[1]/span/span/a/b"):
            poster_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'jsc_c_')]/span[1]/span/span/a/b").text
            return poster_name

        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'jsc_c_')]/strong[1]/span/a/span/span"):
            poster_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'jsc_c_')]/strong["
                                                       "1]/span/a/span/span").text
            return poster_name

    except NoSuchElementException:
        return "No user information found"


while True:
    element_exists = user_element_exist()
    if not element_exists:
        user_name = group_element()
        print(user_name)
        driver.refresh()
    elif element_exists:
        user_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h4[@id][@class][./span[./a]]/span/a").text
        print(user_name)
        driver.refresh()

    # set the sleep timer to fit your needs
    sleep(300) # This sleeps for 300 seconds, which is 5 minutes. 

    # I would likely use a random sleep function
    # sleep(randint(180, 360))
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of log in every 5 minutes try to move that part away from loop to login only once

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
        driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("username")
        driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("password",Keys.RETURN)

        while True:         
            user = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h4[@id][@class][./span[./a]]/span/a"))).text
            print(user)
            time.sleep(60000*5)
```

Also consider to use random interval instead of hardcoded sleep:

```
import random
time.sleep(random.randint(240, 360)) # wait for 4~6 minutes
```